# Why are this elements not at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website where I want the top image to be at the top of the browser, with no extra margins. 
The same thing with the image at the bottom of the browser [Here's the link to the website](http://fullpagewebsite.blogspot.com.ar/).

As you can see, if you scroll down the first top image isn't at the top of the page.. There is a gap between the top of the viewport and the top of the image. The same happens with the bottom image... What can I add to the code?

Comment: I know you linked to your site but it'd be better if you included enough of your code in your question to reproduce the problem: You're going to change or remove this site later and it won't help other visitors to see your question without the related code.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is 128px high, but your `td` elements are 140px high. Change `<td align="center" height="140" valign="middle"></td>` to `<td align="center" height="128" valign="middle"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
    background-position: top center;
}
.footer {
    background-position: bottom center;
}
```

That should fix it. Your images are shorter than the element, and it defaults to being centred (or rather, `middle`d by default).